# How to merge multiple micro-services behind single API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have two micro services, one with address *domainOne.com* and the other one with *domainTwo.com*.
I have created swagger definition for those APIs as well.
I want to give the user access to both of my APIs, but through a single endpoint.
However, when importing the swagger file, I have just two options, either override the existing one or merge the two swagger files.  The second option is more attractive, but none of them fulfill my requirement, since, I have to manually add the endpoints for the newly imported API. (AWS messes the second imported API, and I have to modify each API end point manually).
Second option is two create two APIs, but then the issue arise that both will have different endpoints, and I am again stuck at point 1.
I want the Amazon API Gateway to give one endpoint to the end user, and allow importing multiple swagger files.
I have seen numerous tutorials, but could not find the solution.

P.S:
Actually, I did a customer project on Azure and Azures API Management easily allowed merging multiple APIs behind one single API Management Instance.
Now my current project has AWS stack and I want to achieve the similar thing in AWS API Gateway.
How can i achieve it??

Comment: Why don't you simply merge the two swagger templates into one before importing it into API Gateway?

Comment: @Dunedan, thanks for the your feedback. The issue is that the **host** is not the same for both APIs.  Techincally, a swagger file will have one **host** only.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is fairly easy to accomplish it by using [Custom Domain Name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html).

You should create the 2 APIs, it doesn't matter if they are backed by Lambda, EC2 or ECS/Fargate.

Then you create a custom domain such as: api.domain.com and map each route such as:

- api.domain.com/login -> **api1**/login
- api.domain.com/user  -> **api1**/user
- api.domain.com/search -> **api2**/search
- api.domain.com/order  -> **api2**/order

You might also check this [post](https://medium.com/type-faster/how-to-call-multiple-serverless-micro-services-under-the-same-domain-972b5b9e49dd).